# How to let a user remove an object in canvas 2D from an arbitrary position

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I've got some simple barchart making code written which allows a user to add a barchart but I'd also like to allow them to remove a barchart of choice from the canvas. I don't think this should be overly difficult but I'm relatively new to html and I'm quite unsure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I've written.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>

var barVals = [];

function draw() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // calculate highest bar value (used to scale the rest)
    var highest = 0;
    for (var b=0; b<barVals.length; b++) {
    if (barVals[b]>highest)
    highest=barVals[b];
    }

// we have 8 horizontal lines so calculate an appropriate scale

var lineSpacing = 1;
var highestLine = 7*lineSpacing;

    while (highestLine<highest) {
    lineSpacing *= 10;
    highestLine = 7*lineSpacing;
    }



// grey background

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 600, 450);



// draw and (if we have any data to scale from) label horizontal lines

var lineNum = 0;
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.font="16px sans-serif";
for (y=0; y<=350; y+=50) {

    // line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50,y+50);
    ctx.lineTo(550,y+50);
    ctx.stroke();

    // label (the 6 is an offset to centre the text vertically on the line)

    if (barVals.length>0) {
        ctx.fillText(lineSpacing*lineNum, 10, 400-y+6); 
        lineNum++;
    
    }

}



// draw boxes (widths based on how many we have)

var barWidth = 500/barVals.length;
var halfBarWidth = barWidth/2;
for (b=0; b<barVals.length; b++) {

    // calculate size of box and draw it
    
    var x = 60+b*barWidth;
    var hgt = (barVals[b]/highestLine)*350; // as fraction of highest line
    
    if (b%2==0)
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
    else

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    
    ctx.fillRect(x,400-hgt,barWidth,hgt);

    // calculate position of text and draw it

    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(barVals[b]);
    var halfTextWidth = metrics.width/2;
    x = 60+halfBarWidth+(b*barWidth)-halfTextWidth;
    ctx.fillText(barVals[b], x, 420-hgt); 

    }

}



function addBar() {

    var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("barVal"); 
    barVals.push(parseInt(textBoxObj.value)); // add new value to end of array. As an integer not a string!!
    draw(); // redraw

    textBoxObj.value = 0;

    }

</script>
</head>
    

<body onload="draw();">
<center>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
<form>
<BR>
<input type=button value='Add Bar' onclick='addBar();'> <input id='barVal' value=0>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing a specific chart isn't much different from adding. In fact you almost have everything you need right in your code yet.

Let's take a look at it. As soon as you click on the "Add Bar" button it will add a value from the associated textbox to the `barVal` array. For example, if there has been a value of 5 and 12 and you would trace the contents of barVal to the console using

```
console.log(barVal);
```

you would see this

> Array [ 5, 12 ]

So 5 is stored at the first position and 12 at the second inside the array. With this knowledge in mind, what about adding a function which simply removes a specific element from the array? Here comes the `array.splice()` function into play. You can pass it an index inside the array and a number of elements it should remove.

e.g. if we want to get rid of the 12, we'd call `barVal.splice(1,1);`

After the element has been removed it's just a matter of updating your graph by calling `draw()` again. Now you might wonder why we pass **1** as the index, as we want to remove the second element - that's because indexes start counting from **0**.

Here's an example:

```js
var barVals = [];

function draw() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // calculate highest bar value (used to scale the rest)
  var highest = 0;
  for (var b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {
    if (barVals[b] > highest)
      highest = barVals[b];
  }

  // we have 8 horizontal lines so calculate an appropriate scale

  var lineSpacing = 1;
  var highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;

  while (highestLine < highest) {
    lineSpacing *= 10;
    highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;
  }



  // grey background

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 450);



  // draw and (if we have any data to scale from) label horizontal lines

  var lineNum = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
  for (y = 0; y <= 350; y += 50) {

    // line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, y + 50);
    ctx.lineTo(550, y + 50);
    ctx.stroke();

    // label (the 6 is an offset to centre the text vertically on the line)

    if (barVals.length > 0) {
      ctx.fillText(lineSpacing * lineNum, 10, 400 - y + 6);
      lineNum++;

    }
  }



  // draw boxes (widths based on how many we have)

  var barWidth = 500 / barVals.length;
  var halfBarWidth = barWidth / 2;
  for (b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {

    // calculate size of box and draw it

    var x = 60 + b * barWidth;
    var hgt = (barVals[b] / highestLine) * 350; // as fraction of highest line

    if (b % 2 == 0)
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    else

      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

    ctx.fillRect(x, 400 - hgt, barWidth, hgt);

    // calculate position of text and draw it

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(barVals[b]);
    var halfTextWidth = metrics.width / 2;
    x = 60 + halfBarWidth + (b * barWidth) - halfTextWidth;
    ctx.fillText(barVals[b], x, 420 - hgt);

  }

}



function addBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("barVal");
  barVals.push(parseInt(textBoxObj.value)); // add new value to end of array. As an integer not a string!!
  draw(); // redraw

  textBoxObj.value = 0;

}

function removeBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("removeBarVal");
  barVals.splice(parseInt(textBoxObj.value), 1);
  draw(); // redraw



}
draw();
```

```html
<center>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
  <form>
    <br>
    <input type=button value='Add Bar' onclick='addBar();'> <input id='barVal' value=0>
    <input type=button value='Remove Bar' onclick='removeBar();'> <input id='removeBarVal' value=0>
  </form>
</center>
```